# Programatically moving a window in Xamarin.mac app

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin

I've been trying to find a way to make a sort of desktop pet to walk around my screen with Visual studio mac and xcode using the xamarin framework.

Im very new to the development of mac apps but tried making a small window that would helpfully walk around randomly... I havent found any info from the countless searches I have made on the internet. I still have a lot of questions like getting rid of the borders and menu or keeping it on top. For now however, I would just like to see it move- I've spent too much time trying to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for any answers, my hope in this project is suffering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608523/c-sharp-wpf-move-the-window

Comment: This doesn’t really seem like it’s the same issue as mine…

Comment: I'll assume you have used `Xamarin.Mac` project template, not `Xamarin.Forms`. As the Xamarin.Mac main doc page says *"Xamarin.Mac exposes the complete macOS SDK for .NET developers to build native Mac applications using C#."* You'll have better success searching for macOS answers written in ObjectiveC or Swift. Then manually translate each line of code into corresponding C#. If can't find similarly named C# `Xamarin.Mac` call, google for it. E.g. `SomeMacClass SomeMacFunction xamarin`.

Comment: thanks, I hadn't thought of manually translating the swift :D